# Vim indenting for Python

Tags: python, vim

My Vim is having trouble with indenting after `:`. For example,

```
with open(filepath, "r") as r_obj:
# Pressing enter comes here
    # Not here
for i in range(100):
    # Indents correctly!
if (condition):
    # Indents correctly!
```

Note that I use `vim-python-pep8-indent`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Vimjas/vim-python-pep8-indent). What's really weird is that if I use for loop, it would indent correctly but it wouldn't if I use the with statement. No matter what I do, it will never indent correctly at the with statement!

I believe indenting is connected to for and if statements because Vim indents correctly even if I remove `:` and `<:>` from `indentkeys`.

Also, note that my current setting is

```
:set indentexpr?
# gives 'indentexpr='
:set indentkeys?
# gives 'indentkeys=0{,0},0),0],:,0#,!^F,o,O,e,<:>
:set cindent?
# gives 'nocindent'
```

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: I do not use that plugin, and my vim correctly indents on with statements. It sounds like you should raise an issue on the author's GitHub.

Comment: I also tried removing the vim plugin and tried to set up myself to fail. What I noticed is that if I type `with open(filename):`, it would indent correctly. If I write something like `with open("filename"):`, however, it wouldn't indent correctly. Essentially, if there is any string inside `open()`, it wouldn't indent correctly.

I tried adding :, <:> to indentkeys, cindentkeys (because I also tried using cindent to solve this problem), and also added with to cinwords, but none of these worked correctly...

Comment: How did you try removing the plugin? did you run vim with `vim --noplugin`? That will avoid loading the plugin. You can also run with `vim -u NORC` to run without your `.vimrc` to see if it's something in there that is causing your issue.

Comment: I use Vundle to manage my Vim plugins. This is good because I confirmed the indentation issue with `vim --noplugin`.

Comment: I guess the next step I can try is to add vim settings one by one with `vim -u NORC`.

Comment: what `:scriptnames` load with `--noplugin`? I posted mine.